# Slow invoking of WCF service

Tags: performance, wcf, windows-phone-7, service

So my issue is kinda simple but can't figure out how to deal with it. 
I am using a wcf service which is accessing database through ADO.NET Entity Framework and after that I use this service to get the data in windows phone 7 application. The problem is when I call a simple select * from  table the data gets populated in my WP7 for like 6-7 seconds which seems to me kinda long. I can post the web.config if needed but I havent changed much from what was generated from VS.

Anyone had the same issue or know how to deal with that?

I put my web.config, I thik problem should be there maybe.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceForWinMobile.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceForWinMobile.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://89.215.65.163/WcfServiceForWinMobile/Win7MobileService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
<connectionStrings><add name="CompanyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xetyccwqk6.database.windows.net;initial catalog=Company;persist security info=True;user id=company;password=Plovdiv12345;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

Comment: Have you profiled yet?

Comment: Excuse me have a what? I can't understand what do you mean :?

Comment: Application profiling, it shows what is taking time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: Oh ok I will try it and tell what's taking time. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Unfortunately I see there is no Performance Profiling for VS 2010 Professional :(

Comment: you can always try the trial of http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: Does it work for wcf services ?